# Find the volume of a solid under the surface $z=x^{2} -y^{2}$ and limited by the $xy$ plane, $x=2$ plane and $x=4$ plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

*Find the volume of a solid under the surface $z=x^{2} -y^{2}$ and limited by the  planes: $xy$,  $x=2$  and $x=4$.*

Can you please tell me whether I'm approaching this problem correctly?

As the region is limited by the $xy$ plane, $z\geq0$. So the volume asked will be $\iint\limits_Rf(x,y)dxdy$ where $R$ is the *base* of the surface (the projection on $xy$).

We define $R$ more accurately as a y-simple region. So $2\le x \le 4$. The bounds of the projection on $xy$ will be those where $0=x^{2} -y^{2} \implies -x\le y \le x$.

The last step is to set the limits for $R$ in the double integral and integrate.$\int\limits_2^4\int\limits_{-x}^xx^{2}-y^{2}dydx=80$

Comment: This seems correct.

Comment: Looks Good, what made you doubt your answer?

Comment: The plane "$xy$" otherwise known as $z=0$?  (A different "John" than above, BTW.)

Comment: @John I wasn't sure about the $-x\le y \le x$ part in the y-simple region.

Comment: Well the "other John" tried to clarify why your correct. To project the surface on the $xy$ plane, you took $z=0$ which after a bit of math leads to $y=-x$ and $y=x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To formalize my comments, I will put it in answer form. First off, your solution is correct. Just to add some clarification, the $xy$ plane is equivalently represented as $z=0$. The triple integral, $\int \int \int_0^{x^2-y^2} dzdydx$ reduces to a double integral that you described above. Next, we take the projection of the surface on the $xy$ plane, by finding the intersection of $z=x^2-y^2$ and $z=0$ which is simply $x^2=y^2$. Following that we draw the projection and deduce the following,

$$V=\int_{2}^{4} \int_{-x}^{x} \int_0^{x^2-y^2} dzdydx$$

The projection should look something like this (the red line is the ray that is drawn to determine the bounds)
[image]

Comment: @jjjx Is something missing in the answer that you haven't upvoted or placed as an accepted answer yet? I couldn't help but notice that all the questions you have asked on this site don't have accepted answers. This site is meant to help not only you but other people who have similar questions. This is facilitated by having upvoted and accepted answers. Furthermore, it makes the life of the hardworking respondents searching for questions that can or need answers easier. I suggest you start accepting answers or declaring why they aren't the answers you wanted or need.

Comment: @jjjx You may upvote by selecting the upper arrow and accept the answer by selecting the tick. Once it is selected, it should turn green.